# CopyItemActivity how to configure

Tags: workflow, visual-studio

I want to copy an item using a workflow in VS. So i've used the copyitemactivity.

In the properties what do i put in the  ListItem? I want to reference the current item the workflow is operating on.

[image]

I found this link but dont understand how. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/5b8d8806-4211-4a37-8d45-747fb41997da/

Where do I go to bind?
[image]

Thanks